# Angular 5 filtering all columns at the same through a single mat input search box using material table

Tags: angular

I want to filter column specific values through a single mat input search.i have gone through soutions in stackbilz where there are different search inputs for different columns. Any example where we can filter all columns through a single mat input search using filter predicate ??

Answer (score 0):

> try out these using grd-filter.pipe.ts
>
> [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsve5n)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'grdFilter'
})
export class GrdFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
    if (!filter){
      return items;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(items)){
      return items;
    }

    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);

      if (defaultFilter) {
        return items.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] == "", true));
      }
      else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] == "";
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
 
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  public searchText : string;
  public customerData : any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerData = [
      {"name": 'Anil kumar', "Age": 34, "blog" :'https://code-view.com'},
      {"name": 'Sunil Kumar Singh', "Age": 28, "blog" :'https://code-sample.xyz'},
      {"name": 'Sushil Singh', "Age": 24, "blog" :'https://code-sample.com'},
      {"name": 'Aradhya Singh', "Age": 5, "blog" :'https://code-sample.com'},
      {"name": 'Reena Singh', "Age": 28, "blog" :'https://code-sample.com'},
      {"name": 'Alok Singh', "Age": 35, "blog" :'https://code-sample.com'},
      {"name": 'Dilip Singh', "Age": 34, "blog" :'https://code-sample.com'}];
  }
}
```

> .html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox">
<p></p>
<table *ngFor="let emp of customerData | grdFilter: {name: searchText, Age:searchText,  blog: searchText}; let i=index;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 5%;">{{i +1}}</td>
    <td style="width: 10%;">{{emp.name}}</td>
    <td style="width: 5%;">{{emp.Age}}</td>
    <td style="width: 15%;">{{emp.blog}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My issue is using this.dataSource.filter = filterValue, it is filtering out from the json since i am passing the entire json, some of the contents are not present in the table as well. Is there a way with which it can be achievable like, lets say if the content is not available in the table. it should not search in a ANGULAR MATERIAL TABLE